# Does LaTeX (lualatex) have the Adobe Illustrator equivalent of "Outline" mode?

Tags: luatex, adobe

I am working with a manufacturer (there are some language barriers) who is asking for the "outline" of some of my pdfs.  What they mean: they want what Adobe Illustrator does in its "Outline" submenu.   It looks something like this (we had a native AI file and were able to generate this):
[image]

Does anyone know if there's a way to generate the equivalent from my latex (lualatex in particular) file?  This is, I believe, for cut zones/bleed zones and the like.

I am hoping for either

1. A lualatex package or style (I modify the source by adding a package or use the `outline` style instead of the `article` style) (or)
2. A tool that allows pdfs to be converted for AI (or)
3. A methodology from within AI to read my lualatex .pdf file

Help?

I am grasping at straws here, so I don't expect an answer, but perhaps someone has stumbled over this before.

(We are still seeing if we can Adobe Illustrator to read my lualatex pdf files, but all currently available information says that AI can only generate the outline from a native AI file).

Comment: The `geometry` package has the options `showframe` to show the text area and `showcrop` to display crop marks.

Comment: What exactly does the outline add? Does that depend on the content of the page? If not (or if it is the same as long as all pages have equal width and height), you could try to overlay each page with a watermark-like drawing, see https://ctan.org/search/?phrase=watermark for some options.